# angular layout takes to much space

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

```
<body>
    <div layout="column" flex>
        <div>
            <h2>Hello</h2>
        </div>
        <div layout="row">
            <div flex="30">
                <md-content>
                    //some code     
                </md-content>
            </div>
            <div flex="70">
                //some code
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want the content of "md-content" to fill the rest of the screen-height.
If I write "layout-fill", the size of the md-content is exactly the screen size, but because of the first nested div with the h2 in it, the site is getting higher than my screen.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly what you want is to get something like this :

```
---------------------
|       Hello       |
|--------------------
| div 30|    div 70 |
|       |           |
|       |           |
---------------------
```

And this whole content is supposed to fit in the full screen without any scroll, right ?
If so : multiple options depending on whether you want to do it with pure css or using material library.

**Option 1: CSS**

You might consider forcing the initial div to calc(100vh - myDivSize) and flexing the row div

**Option 2: Material option**

http://embed.plnkr.co/T9vRQhbHDR5w2F0Lnu0R/preview Check this plunker out, bare in mind the applied 100 vh on the main div is just for plunkr purpose and shouldn't be used this way on your app.